# Homorphism between groups and generators

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $f: G \rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism of finite groups.

Since $G$ is finitely generated, $G = \langle x_1 , ... , x_n \rangle$. Is it then true that $H = \langle f(x_1), ... , f(x_n) \rangle$? Or is this only true when $f$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: What if $f(x_i) = 1$ for all $i = 1,\ldots,n$?

Comment: Then $f$ would be trivial, @dcolazin.

Comment: @Shaun then $<f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_n)> = \{1\} \neq H$ in general. If $f$ is surjective, then $\forall h \in H \ \exists g \in G \ h = f(g) = f(\text{product of some generators}) = \text{product} f (\text{some generators})$.

Comment: The map $\iota:G\to H$ given by $\iota(g)=e_H$ for all $g\in G$ is trivially a homomorphism, @dcolazin; check it yourself.

Comment: @Shaun obviously it is a homomorphism, but the image of the trivial map is not the whole codomain!

Comment: This is true if and only if $f$ is surjective, because $<f(x_1), ..., f(x_n)> = Im(f)$.

Comment: It's still a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ by definition. I don't see your problem here.

Comment: @Shaun that the question is asking when $H = < f(x_1), \ldots, f(x_n)> = f(G)$

Comment: Oh, I see! My mistake, @dcolazin. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You should prove that, in fact:

$$\langle f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n)\rangle = \operatorname{im}(f).$$

This means that $H$ is generated by the $f(x_i)$ exactly when $H = \operatorname{im}(f)$, i.e. when $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the homomorphism $\iota: \Bbb Z_3\to \Bbb Z_6$ given by $\iota(g)=0$ for all $g\in \Bbb Z_3$.

> Hint: Consider $|\Bbb Z_3|$ and $|\Bbb Z_6|$.

Also, consider $\pi: \Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3\to \Bbb Z_3$ given by $(g,h)\mapsto h$. Then $\pi$ is surjective but your property holds.

In fact, it is true if and only if $f$ is surjective.